# What is the meaning of ^M in 'git diff'?

Tags: git, line-endings

I am diffing a file between forked and upstream Bitbucket repositories:

`$ git diff origin/branchA..upstream/branchB -- some/file/path.xyz`

It seems to return the same difference for almost every file:

```
-<U+FEFF>@using Sitecore.Mvc
+@using Sitecore.Mvc^M
```

What is the exact meaning of `^M` that only shows up after the first line? I see this issue when I compare other files as well. I am on a [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 machine. `core.autocrlf` is set to `true`. The .gitattributes is set to `text eol=lf`. My Git version is 2.5.1.windows.1.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`^M` represents [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). This diff means something removed a [Unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) from the beginning of the line and added a CR at the end.

The `^` symbol stands for Control, so `^M` means <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>.

To get from that to the actual ASCII character code, you take the base character and flip bit 6 (i.e. XOR with 64). For letters, that just means subtract 64. So e.g. `^A` is character code 1 (because `A` is 65). `^M` is 77 - 64 = 13 (because `M` is 77), which corresponds to carriage return in ASCII.

Comment: I love answers like this that "teach a man to fish".  Not only do I now understand `^M`, but also potentially any other such control characters I may encounter in the future.

Comment: `git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol` to hide it from the diff

Comment: If you're here because git in WSL (Ubuntu) is showing every file changed with carriage returns vs. git in Windows or VS code showing no differences, you might need `git config --global core.autocrlf true` instead. See: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/184#issuecomment-209913528